# Apache Camel, calling one route from another

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I have two routes in one camel context.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:facebook.properties"
            id="properties" />
        <route>
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8765/getLikes" />
            <to uri="facebook" />
        </route>

        <route>
            <from uri="facebook://userLikes?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&amp;oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&amp;oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}" />
            <log message="The message contains ${body}" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

In second route I use facebook component.
I want to call http://localhost:8765/getLikes and get all likes from facebook which second route will get. But first route cannot find the second one

Comment: You have to use components like `direct` (http://camel.apache.org/direct) or `seda`  (http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) for this.

Comment: ok, in first route I use <to uri="direct:facebook" /> but it doesn't help: "No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://facebook]"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use components like **direct** (http://camel.apache.org/direct) or **seda** (http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) for this:

```
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:facebook.properties"
            id="properties" />
        <route>                
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8765/getLikes" />
            <to uri="direct:facebook" />
        </route>

        <route>
            <from uri="direct:facebook" />
            <!-- Maybe you need to set some headers here -->
            <to uri="facebook://userLikes?oAuthAppId={{oAuthAppId}}&amp;oAuthAppSecret={{oAuthAppSecret}}&amp;oAuthAccessToken={{oAuthAccessToken}}" />
            <log message="The message contains ${body}" />
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

This link https://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html can be helpful for you too.